How to tune grid lines in pgadmin erd tool
I see grid lines on canvas, drawing element snap to those grid lines, however rectangles representing tables are not sized as multiple of grids. Due to this missalignment it is more difficult to align connections nicely This image illustrates the missaligment
I have tried to find something in configuration, failed; then I have saved my drawing and I looked to the pgerd file itself, like playing with gridSize parameter, then import back the file, but I have failed to change the grid lines to match to tables

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can raise this to https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues. FWIW, I'm the author of ERD in pgAdmin.
